# Decomposition of number into prime numbers

Tags: algorithm, pascal

I'm trying to create a pascal program for decomposition of prime numbers, i.e.

```
16 = 2*2*2*2
210 = 2*3*5*7
```

I should input a number and I should return the prime numbers decomposition. I don't understand the solution in mathematical sense, could someone explain me this algorithm or pseudo code, as long as I understand what I'm creating programming isn't really an issue.

Thanks

Comment: [Which algorithm?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms)

Comment: Do you know how to just test if a number is a prime or not? The common algorithms that do this all can be easily adapted to produce the factorization.

Comment: London, do you know how to do it using just paper and pencil? Let's take some number and try it. If you know how to do it then just write it in programming language isn't that hard.

Comment: If you don't understand those solutions in a mathematical sense, then this is a math question, not a programming question, so I've voted to close this question as *off topic*. Please ask on math.stackexchange.com instead. The term you're looking for is *prime factorization*. It's a concept I learned about in 7th grade.

Comment: As @missingno said, the algorithm to test and find primes is Sieve of Earatosthenes algorithm. I provoded a solution below based on that.

Answer (score 9):

A naive way of doing this is to:

```
k = 2
N = 210
while N > 1:
    if N % k == 0:   // if k evenly divides into N
        print k      // this is a factor
        N = N / k    // divide N by k so that we have the rest of the number left.
    else:
        k = k + 1
```

The main premise, is that `FACTOR(N)` is equal to   `k * FACTOR(N / k)`, if k divides N. So keep doing this over and over until you can no longer factor `N`. This way, you get `k1 * k2 * k3 * FACTOR(N / k1 / k2 / k3)` etc.

If you start with small numbers and work up, you'll only pull out the prime factors.

So, for 210, you get:

```
k = 2
N = 210

k divides N, so print 2, N becomes 105
k no longer divides N, so k becomes 3
k divides N, so print 3, N becomes 35
k no longer divides N, so k becomes 4
k does not divide N, so k becomes 5
k divides N, so print 5, N becomes 7
k no longer divide N, so k becomes 6
k does not divide N, so k becomes 7
k divides N, so print 7, N becomes 1
N is now equal to 1, so stop.

You get 2 3 5 7
```

A basic improvement would be that you only have to iterate through the primes. So, you could have skipped over 4 and 6 in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

A prime number is an integer with exactly two divisors.  For example, `13` is prime, since it is divisible only by `1` and by `13` (two divisors).  `14` is not prime, since it is divisible by `1`, `2`, `7` and `14` (four divisors).  `4` is not prime, since it is divisible by `1`, `2` and `4` (three divisors).  By convention, `1` is not a prime number, but that's not really important here.

Every integer larger than 1 has a unique factorization (decomposition) into prime numbers.  In other words, there is only one (multi)set of prime numbers such that their product is equal to the given number.  For example:

```
14 = 2 * 7
16 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
4 = 2 * 2
13 = 13
```

Your task is to write an algorithm that takes on input an integer larger than 1 and outputs a list of prime numbers such that their product is equal to the input number.

Arguably the easiest algorithm for factorization is [trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division).

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases to consider with the number you get as input:

1) The number is a prime number (in which case there is no factorization possible. You should just return the number as output)

2) The number is not a prime number (It can be factored into product of primes)

I will outline the steps below. Note that I am using another famous algorithm. I do not know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

1) Use Sieve Of Eratosthenes algorithm ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes ) to find all the primes less than your input. In this process you can also determine if your input is a prime number.

2) Now if your number is not a prime, see the first prime that divides it and continue tracking each of the number you get as quotient.

Here is a nice illustration: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m2cdWorIq8

Example:

Suppose you receive input as 12.

```
(Operation , Input , Output)

       -      12     -
     12/2     6      2
     6/2      3      2*2
     3/2      3      2*2
     3/3      1      2*2*3
```

The algorithm stops if you hit a prime or 1 in the Input field.

As you can see the key here is to know the primes (2, 3, 5 ...) so that you can divide your input with them. Also you need to determine if your input is prime. Both can be accomplished with Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 1):

based on Donald Miner answer, I did a bash function:

```
function decompose(){
    r=$(
            k=2;
            N=$1;
            while [ $N -gt 1 ] && [ $(( k ** 2 )) -le $N ];
            do [ "$(( N % k ))" == 0 ] && 
            {
                    echo $k; N=$(( N/k ));
            } || let k++; 
            done
            [ $(( k ** 2 )) -gt $N ] && echo $N
    );
    echo "$r" | uniq | 
    while read n;
    do echo "$n^$(
            echo "$r" | grep '^'"$n"'$' | wc -l
    )";
    done |
    tr '\n' '*' | 
    sed 's/\(\^1\)\?\*$//g; s/\^1\([^0-9]\)/\1/g'; 
    echo;
}
```

Some samples:

```
$ decompose 768
2^8*3
$ decompose 110
2*5*11
$ decompose 686567
7*98081
$ echo "7*98081" | bc
686567
```

As said, it can be much faster if get the prime number instead of increment k but seems good to me.

Comment: Try `decompose 897`; the answer should be `3 * 13 * 23`, but your code claims that it is `3^3 * 13 * 23`.  You need the `grep $n` to be more precise.  I'm not completely sure that a shell script is appropriate for a question tagged algorithm and Pascal.

Comment: Fixed, this time I tested with `bc` until 10000, let me know if you find more bugs. Thanks.

Comment: What you've written will work with any variant of `grep`.  If you used GNU `grep`, you could use `grep -w "$n"` to get the job done succinctly.